# How can I unset an environment variable in Open Firmware?

Tags: macos, firmware, forth

I am attempting to understand [Open Firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Firmware) on my machine and to experiment, I tried some Forth words/programs from an old Apple technical note.

As part of a program, I used the word **setenv** to create and set a new environment variable. It is quite harmless, but I cannot get rid of the variable!

In one example I saw, the word **unsetenv** was used, but there is no **unsetenv** on my machine!

The system is: iMac G5 (3.1) 20 inch iSight 2.1 GHz PowerPC 970FX (G5).

The ROM details as listed are: Apple PowerMac 12.1. 5.2.6f1 BootROM built on 10/05/2005 at 18.02.54

<sub>There is possibly a simple answer to this trivial, but irritating problem.</sub>

Comment: You can check your system for other words according to the Open Firmware sources, [search for unsetenv](https://github.com/openbios/openfirmware/search?q=unsetenv&type=Code). Perhaps it can help you.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help and editing! The sources you referred to have been most helpful. I still have not worked out where the referenced unsetenv is coming from, at a pinch I might be able to program it myself, but that seems silly if there is already a forth word unsetenv (there isn't in the standard definition). I can, of course, reset everything by holding down option-cmd-r-p on power up.